# Power Set Proof Verification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This is really simple, but the next part of the problem calls for me to use this proof to show that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contains $2^n$ elements so if anyone could verify this that would be great.

**Problem**

Let $A$ be a finite set, say $A$ has $n$ elements, and let $x \notin A$. Find the set B such that $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap B = \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{P}(A \cup ${$x$}$) = \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$

**My Proof**
Let $B = ${$x$} 
 i) $x \notin A \implies x \notin \mathcal{P}(A) \implies \mathcal{P}(A) \cap B=\varnothing$ 
ii) $B =$ {$x$} $ \implies \mathcal{P}(A) \cup ${$x$}$ = \mathcal{P}(A) \cup B$

If this proof seems correct (which I'm pretty sure it is) any help on using this to show that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contains $2^n$ elements would be great!

Comment: Are you trying to show $P(A) \cap B = \emptyset$ or $P(A) \cup B = \emptyset$? Also, are you trying to show $P(A \cup \{x\}) = P(A \cup B)$ or $P(A) \cup \{x\} = P(A) \cup B$? Your proof's results do not match the question's demands. You may have typos.

Comment: My apologies, that union was supposed to be an intersection. The typo has been fixed now. I am trying to find a set B such that both the (new) requirements are satisfied. I think my proof does (now) satisfy them both.

Comment: There's a simpler way, by the way, which is to note that a selection of a subset $S$ of $A = \{1, 2, \dots, n \}$ is precisely a statement of whether $1 \in S$, $2 \in S$, and so on up to $n \in S$. There are $2^n$ possible such combinations of statements: a factor of 2 provided by each element.

Comment: There are also a few things that need revision in logic. Namely, $x\notin A$ doesn't imply $x\notin P(A)$, otherwise the contrapositive would imply $P(A)\subseteq A$.